# Converting series element to int

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas series-

```
3959    2019
Name: DATE, dtype: int64
```

which has only one element.

I wanted to convert that element to integer. I did-

```
for i in last_row_year.to_numpy():
    last_year=i
```

to get `last_year` as `2019` (int type)

Is there a more pythonic way to do this?

Comment: if it has only one element why for loop?

Comment: Try `last_row_year.item()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be more pythonic:

```
last_year = last_row_year.to_numpy()[0]
```

Answer (score 3):

Singleton series can be converted to a scalar via [`.item()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.item.html):

```
s = pd.Series([1]) 
s 

0    1
dtype: int64
```

```
s.item()
# 1
```

Note that this only works on series of length 1. For a more generic solution that always grabs the first element of any series regardless of length, `.iloc[0]` or `.to_numpy()[0]` is preferred.

Comment: Should `s.to_numpy()[0]` be used over `s.iloc[0]`?

Comment: @Ch3steR Yeah, that would work too, in fact I'd probably say that's better.

Comment: Another approach using tuple unpacking `[val] = s` work with Series with only 1 element, I timeit all three approaches all had ~`1-3µs` difference. And got to know about `.item` +1

Comment: @Ch3steR `.item()` may or may not be useful, depending on how you want to handle errors. I prefer being explicit and failing, but this depends on the situation.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a series with only one element, `int(element)` will suffice.

Comment: The question was how to convert a pandas series with one `int64` element into a python `int`. This does that. Compare the output of `x = pd.Series([2019]); print(x)` with `print(int(x))`. `x[0]` or `x.to_numpy()[0]` will also work (as you point out in your answer), but I think `int(x)` shows more clearly that the expected result is an integer, and will raise an error if it is not.